# SQL pass values from table sequentially through SELECT clause and save results to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, select, range

I am faced with a situation in SQL where I want to essentially loop through a query and have it run multiple times while replacing values in parts of the SELECT statement with those from another table. A simplified example included below.

**Table1**

```
+---------+-------+
| Product | Price |
+---------+-------+
| A       | 2     |
+---------+-------+
| B       | 4     |
+---------+-------+
| C       | 6     |
+---------+-------+
| D       | 1     |
+---------+-------+
```

**Table2**

```
+--------+
| Volume |
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+
| 2      |
+--------+
| 3      |
+--------+
```

**Current Query Starting Point**

```
SELECT 
     PRODUCT
    ,1 AS 'VOLUME'
    ,PRICE
    ,(PRICE * 1) AS 'REVENUE'
FROM dbo.Table1
```

I started with this query to provide the information when VOLUME = 1, but am stuck trying to figure out how to have the '1' be dynamic and run for all values in Table2

**Desired Output in Table3**

```
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| Product | Price | Volume | Revenue |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| A       | 2     | 1      | 2       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| B       | 4     | 1      | 4       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| C       | 6     | 1      | 6       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| D       | 1     | 1      | 1       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| A       | 2     | 2      | 4       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| B       | 4     | 2      | 8       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| C       | 6     | 2      | 12      |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| D       | 1     | 2      | 2       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| A       | 2     | 3      | 6       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| B       | 4     | 3      | 12      |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| C       | 6     | 3      | 18      |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| D       | 1     | 3      | 3       |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cross join

```
 Select t1.product, t1.price, t2.volume, 
     t2.volume * t1.price revenue
 from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
```

TEST IT

```
declare @t1 table (product char(1), price int)
declare @t2 table (volume int)
insert @t1(product, price)
values ('A', 2), ('B', 4),('C', 6),('D', 1)
insert @t2(volume) values (1), (2), (3)

Select t1.product, t1.price, t2.volume, 
     t2.volume * t1.price revenue
 from @t1 t1 cross join @t2 t2
```

Comment: Thanks! This provides the desired results set. Do you know of an alternative to run the query separately for each record from Table 2? The real-life example is more complex and I would have performance concerns about CROSS JOIN being able to successfully run.

Comment: First question is what are you trying to do?  Do you need the results for all combinations, or just for those from one volume in table2? If the former, you have to read all data in both tables from disk. Many queries, (unless appropriate indexes at in place) must do this). But if you really only need combinations from one volume, either change the cross join to an ordinary join with an `On` condition, or add a where clause that restricts the SQL statement to whatever record[s] from table2 you want it to process.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run the calculations in batches, then you may want to use a loop:

```
DECLARE @i INT=
(
    SELECT MIN(Volume)
    FROM dbo.Table2
);

WHILE @i IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT t1.PRODUCT,
            t1.PRICE,
            t2.Volume,
            (t1.PRICE * t2.Volume) AS Revenue
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1
            INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 t2
                ON t2.Volume BETWEEN @i AND @i + 10;


    SET @i =
    (
        SELECT MIN(Volume)
        FROM dbo.Table2
        WHERE Volume > @i + 10
    );
END;
```

Comment: Thanks! This provides the desired results set. Do you know of an alternative to run the query separately for each record from Table 2? The real-life example is more complex and I would have performance concerns about CROSS JOIN being able to successfully run.